# "Dieser Vorfall wird gemeldet" - "This will be reported" - OK, but where?

Tags: sudo, lxterminal

I'm currently creating a little community for our RPi in our student community. I created a group called `community` and put the four new users in it. Now I tested all users and they work fine. I didn't add them to the group `sudo`, so they couldn't use root-commands, etc.

Well, I forgot I wasn't user `pi`, but executed `sudo apt-get install ...`.

Now my computer gave me this:

```
Nutzer ist nicht in der sudoers-Datei. Dieser Vorfall wird gemeldet.
```

In English it means:

```
User is not in the sudoers-file. This event will be reported.
```

I get why this is appearing but I don't understand WHERE it is reported to? Since I am the pi unser and the root user, I should have been messaged, but nothing happened. Where is the try to execute a command as root illegily reported to.

Please tell me where is a message and if it's not there by default, how to activate it?

Comment: Have a look in `/var/spool/mail` and see if there is a `root` file there.  This mechanism is one which makes more sense on larger scale systems or inet servers.  I don't know if it can be changed but you might read through, e.g., `man sudoers`.

Comment: It assumes that an email will be send to root, however, since nobody but @goldilocks can configure `sendmail` anymore it usually isn't.

Comment: Goldilocks gave up on configuring `sendmail` a long time ago and sought greener pastures.  I think there is a 1500 page book still in print though, check your local library. But hint: It may take you less time to write your own MTA.